# Evaluate Surface Integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the $$\int_S { \vec{D} \cdot} d\vec{s}$$ over the surface $\vec{D} = 2y\vec{a_x} +  xz\vec{a_y} +z\vec{a_z}$. The cube's coordinates are from $x,y,z\in{(0,2)}$. I am struggling to find it none zero, because I do $$\int_{top} {\vec{D} \cdot} d\vec{s} - \int_{bot} {\vec{D} \cdot} d\vec{s} + \int_{right} {\vec{D} \cdot} d\vec{s} - \int_{left} {\vec{D} \cdot} d\vec{s} + \int_{front} {\vec{D} \cdot} d\vec{s} - \int_{back} {\vec{D} \cdot} d\vec{s} = 0$$ But then I check using the divergence theorem and get 8. I am not sure what I am doing wrong to get 0 on the surface integral since it seems to me it all cancels out. Any help?

Comment: The question is not entirely clear.. Is $S$ the cube? You should rather write $x,y,z\in (0,2)$ instead of the misleading equality. So, the surface is the boundary $\partial S$ of this cube, and $D$ is the *integrand* vector field, isn't it? Also, $(dot)$ is available by the  \cdot   command..

Comment: S is supposed to mean take the surface integral of the cube.

Comment: And how did you get $0$?

Comment: Well I just get inverses for the sides. For example, top and bottom I get: integral(zdxdy) - integral(zdxdy)

Comment: Yes yes, but on the top $z=2$ (constantly), while on the bottom, $z=0$. *That* makes the difference. I'm not sure neither in the other $2$ integrals that they will cancel out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral on the top face is
$$\int_{top}\vec D\cdot d\vec s = \int_{(z=2)\cap \partial S} 0\cdot 2y+0\cdot xz+1\cdot z\ dxdy=\int_{x=0}^2\int_{y=0}^2 2\,dxdy = 8.$$

While the same for the bottom face (the normal vector now looks in the opposite direction: $\pmatrix{0\\0\\-1}$ -- that corresponds to the negative sign in your formulation) gives $\ 0\ $ as $z=0$ on the bottom face.